# Syntax error with a sql query

Tags: php, mysql

Below is the code, but i am getting this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Any help will be very appreciated.

```
 <?php
 include("../includes/conn.php");
 $sql = "SELECT * 
 FROM  `t_maincontent`
 where uid_page =". $_GET['page'] ;
 $results = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
 $content = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
 //print $content['nv_content']."¬".$content['nv_title']."¬".$content['nv_meta'];
 ?>
```

Comment: You don't need to put your PHP code here, but foremost the SQL query itself. That also helps you to better formulate the question (which part in context of the SQL is not clear with the error message) and also to learn how to troubleshoot these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read about the very basics on doing database queries from PHP.

You should check whether `$_GET['page']` exists via `isset( $_GET['page'] );` only send the query if it exists.

```
include( '../includes/conn.php' );
if( isset( $_GET['page'] ) )
{
    /* cast to int would be enough to cancel SQL injection attacks */
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM  t_maincontent WHERE uid_page = ' . (int) $_GET['page'] ;
    $results = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $content = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a link how the user can successfully prevent SQL injections here. You at least give the hint that something utterly wrong is with the code (while others not even leave that warning).

Comment: Thanks for all your advice and help